# Is there a way to substitute \ with / for Gnu Make command goals?

Tags: windows, makefile, portability, gnu-make

I'm running a recursive make on windows using targets for each directory using forward slashes to separate path components. If someone runs

```
> make foo/bar
```

it will run fine. But if someone runs

```
> make foo\bar
```

it won't find the target to build:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `foo\bar'.
```

I would love it if I could add something like this to my top level Makefile:

```
MAKECMDGOALS = $(subst \,/,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

But such things do not work. MAKECMDGOALS can only be read. Or even if I can make backslash targets for all my regular targets like this:

```
$(DIRS): %: $(subst /,\,%)
```

But this too doesn't work. Whats the best way around this?

Comment: Instead of trying to be all-things-to-all-people and complicating your Makefile, teach your users to use forward slashes. Even Windows understands them...

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out a fairly nice way of handling this without resorting to a script to wrap make:

```
# $(call bstarget, foo foo/bar baz frob/niz)
# will result in the following targets being defined in place:
#   foo\bar: foo/bar
#   brob\niz: from/niz
bstarget = $(eval \
    $(foreach TARGET, $1, \
        $(if $(findstring /, $(TARGET)), \
            $(call bstargeteval, $(subst /,\,$(TARGET)), $(TARGET)))))
define bstargeteval
$1: $2

endef
```

Then it can be called in my Makefile with $(call bstarget, $(DIRS))

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 4 backslashes (escaping) in your subst expression.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution and explains *why* it works.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.